# how partition works on the data from mapper to reducer?

Tags: hadoop-streaming, partition

I'm using **hadoop streaming** to process a huge file.
 Say I have a file, each line is a number, I want to split this file into 2 files, one containing odd
 numbers, the other even.

Using hadoop, I might specify 2 reducers for this job, cause when the numbers go from mapper to
 reducer, I thought the number goes to which reducer is determined by `number % 2`, right?

But I was told otherwise, it's not simply `number % 2` but **`hash(number) % 2`** which makes a number
 go to which reducer, is that true?

If so, How could I make it? Can I specify a Partitioner or something to make it right?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the split in your mapper?

For example, each mapper does

```
if int(number) % 2 == 0:
  # Output "EVEN", number
else:
  # Output "ODD", number
```

Then reduce over two keys: EVEN and ODD, writing them to the appropriate file.